# PyGame Not Drawing X

Tags: python, pygame

Hello I am making a tic tac toe game in pygame the problem i encountered is that when i draw an x on the board it does not draw.it works when i draw a circle as shown in the code. please tell me how to fix also can you tell me how to take turns in this game because i cannot figure out how to draw an x and let the computer draw an o and so on.i want to wait for the user to draw an x and then let the computer draw an o.
Here Is The Code:

```py
import pygame,random

pygame.init()

width = 600

height = 600

res = (width,height)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(res)

pygame.display.set_caption("Tic Tac Toe")

background = (255,150,150)

color_light = (170,170,170)

color_dark = (100,100,100)

hover_color = (255, 204, 203)

rect_list = [

    pygame.Rect(10, 10, 180, 190),
    pygame.Rect(200, 10, 190, 190),
    pygame.Rect(400, 10, 190, 190),
    pygame.Rect(10, 210, 180, 180),
    pygame.Rect(200, 210, 190, 180),
    pygame.Rect(400, 210, 190, 180),
    pygame.Rect(10, 400, 180, 190),
    pygame.Rect(200, 400, 190, 190),
    pygame.Rect(400, 400, 190, 190)]

clicked_list = [0 for _ in rect_list]

count = 0


def draw_x(x,y,width,height):

    for i in range(5):
        pygame.draw.aaline(screen,"blue",(x+i,y),(width+x+i,height+y))  # start_pos(x+thickness,y)---end_pos(width+x+thickness,height+y)
        pygame.draw.aaline(screen,"blue",(width+x+i,y),(x+i,height+y))  # start_pos(x+width+thickness,y)---end_pos(x+thickness,y+height)


def draw_line():

    line_color = (212, 212, 255)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, line_color, (190,10,10,580))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, line_color, (390, 10, 10, 580))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, line_color, (10, 200, 580, 10))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, line_color, (10, 390, 580, 10))


def highlight():

    for rect in rect_list:
        if rect.collidepoint(mouse):   
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,hover_color,rect)


def random_no():

    randomno = random.randint(0,len(rect_list)-1)
    if clicked_list[randomno] != 1:
        pass
    else:
        random_no()
    return randomno


def mouse_click():

    x_turn = True
    y_turn = False
    o_no = random_no()
    clicked_list[o_no] = 2
    for i,rect in enumerate(rect_list):
        if clicked_list[i] == 1:
            if x_turn and clicked:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, background, rect)
                draw_x(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height)
        if clicked_list[i] == 2:
            if y_turn:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, background, rect)
                pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, "blue", rect, 5)
            # rect_list.remove(rect_list[i])
            # clicked_list.remove(clicked_list[i])
while True:

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x = screen.get_at(mouse)[:3]
    screen.fill(background)
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        if ev.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            clicked = True
            for i, rect in enumerate(rect_list):
                if rect.collidepoint(ev.pos) and x == hover_color:
                    clicked_list[i] = 1
    draw_line()
    highlight()
    mouse_click()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouse click must be handled in the event loop. However, you need a function `draw_borad` that draws "X" and "O".

Add a variable that indicates if its the turn of "X" or "O":

```py
x_turn = True
```

If the mouse is pressed and a field is empty (0), change the status of the field and change the `x_turn` variable:

```py
if rect.collidepoint(ev.pos) and x == hover_color:
    if clicked_list[i] == 0:
        clicked_list[i] = 1 if x_turn else 2
        x_turn = not x_turn
```

Draw all the "X" and "O" in `draw_borad`:

```py
def draw_borad():
    for i,rect in enumerate(rect_list):
        if clicked_list[i] == 1:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, background, rect)
            draw_x(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height)
        if clicked_list[i] == 2:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, background, rect)
            pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, "blue", rect, 5)

x_turn = True
while True:
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x = screen.get_at(mouse)[:3]
    screen.fill(background)
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        if ev.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            clicked = True
            for i, rect in enumerate(rect_list):
                if rect.collidepoint(ev.pos) and x == hover_color:
                    if clicked_list[i] == 0:
                        clicked_list[i] = 1 if x_turn else 2
                        x_turn = not x_turn

    draw_line()
    highlight()
    draw_borad()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thanks You It Worked

Answer (score 0):

A better way of drawing an 'X' is by drawing two separate lines.

```
def drawX(x,y):
  pygame.draw.lines(screen, black, True, [(x-50,y-50),(x+50,y+50)], 3)
  pygame.draw.lines(screen, black, True, [(x-50,y+50),(x+50,y-50)], 3)
```